# What is the relation between $\mathbb{C}[M]$ and $\mathbb{C}[M/U]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, group-actions

Let $M$ be a variety and let $U$ be a group. By definition, $M/U$ is the space of all $U$-orbits of $M$. Now we take coordinate rings $\mathbb{C}[M]$ and $\mathbb{C}[M/U]$. What is the relation between these two rings? What are the elements in $\mathbb{C}[M/U]$ look like? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $U$ acts on $M$, then it acts on $\mathbf{C}[M]$ too. $\mathbf{C}[M/U]$ "ought to be" the subring of fixed points of $U$; think of them as functions on $M$ that are constant when restricted to orbits of $U$. I don't know if there are any technical subtleties that will cause problems in the algebraic geometry setting.

Answer (score 1):

Given your action of $U$ on $M$, there exists **in the  category of topological spaces** a quotient topological space $M/U $and a continuous map  $\pi: M\to M/U$ with all sorts of nice properties.
The catch, however is that in general there is no reasonable way to endow $M/U$ with the structure of complex manifold:
A counterexample is $M=\mathbb C^n$ and $U=GL_n(\mathbb C)$ acting in the obvious way.
The quotient topological space has two points, one  corresponding to the set $\mathbb C^n \setminus \{0\}$ of non-zero vectors and the other to the singleton set $\{0\}$.
It is connected but not Hausdorff and there is no reasonable  structure of complex manifold on that quotient.
A reasonable sufficient for a quotient manifold to exist is that $U$ be a Lie group and that the action be free and proper.
Examples are $U=$discrete group,  which yields a covering space, but also the non discrete $U=\mathbb C^*$ acting on $\mathbb C^n \setminus \{0\}$ and yielding projective space $\mathbb P^ {n-1}(\mathbb C)$.
The case of algebraic varieties (or rather schemes) is a whole branch  of algebraic geometry: Mumford wrote [a book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_invariant_theory) on the subject which earned him a Fields medal in 1974.

Answer (score 0):

If $M$ is an affine variety and $U$ is a finite group then $M/U$ is also an affine variety (this is proved by Hilbert - Noether in a more general settings). More generally, if $U$ is a *reductive group* then $M/U$ is an affine variety (this result is due to Nagata). In this case, $\mathbb{C}[M/U] = \mathbb{C}[M]^U,$ the invariant subring of $\mathbb{C}[M].$ But for general group $U,$ the invariant subring $\mathbb{C}[M]^U$ may not be finitely generated algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ and hence it will not have any variety structure. For the case of projective variety, there are notions of *good quotient* and *geometric quotient.* This branch of algebraic geometry is called *Geometric Invariant Theory.* You can look at *"Introduction to Moduli Problems and Orbit Spaces"* by P. E. Newstead.